# Laravel eloquent set array key

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to create an array where the key is equal to the returned *ID*. 
But when I execute this code, I only get the timestamps, exists and incrementing values..
There is no way I have to do `toArray()`, because `$arr` is already an array, so no clue why this isn't possible..

```
    $projects = Project::with(array('todos', 'contacts', 'categories'))->get();

    foreach ($projects as $project) {
        $open = Todo::status($project->id, 1)->get()->count();
        $progress = Todo::status($project->id, 2)->get()->count();
        $completed = Todo::status($project->id, 3)->get()->count();

        $project->status = [
            'open' => $open,
            'progress' => $progress,
            'completed' => $completed
        ];

        $arr[$project->id] = $project;
        return $arr;
    }
```

Comment: You `foreach` will only run once, as you stop your method when using a `return statement`.
Back to your issue: What do you get if you `return $project` instead of `return $arr`?

Comment: @PatrickReck I get an array of objects with the incrementing keys [0], [1] etc..

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try it the laravel way:

```
$projects = Project::with(array('todos', 'contacts', 'categories'))->get();

$projects->each(function($project){

        $open = Todo::status($project->id, 1)->get()->count();
        $progress = Todo::status($project->id, 2)->get()->count();
        $completed = Todo::status($project->id, 3)->get()->count();

        $project->status = [
            'open' => $open,
            'progress' => $progress,
            'completed' => $completed
        ];

});

return $projects->toArray();
```

That query returns an illuminate collection object, you can leverage available collection methods rather than wiring it yourself.
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP's intent which was to output an associative array that has project->id as keys.